# bnd plugin for OSGI not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, osgi, bnd

I am using eclipse indigo release. I downloaded the bnd plugin (from http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Download). When i try to right-click on a bnd file and do a 'Make bundle'; I am getting this obscure error message. It says: "The chosen operation is not currently available". If I look in the error log; I see a bunch of errors along the lines of "class load failure: 'aqute.bnd.plugin.popup.scripts'.

I'm stumped.. anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

I've just seen it too. Using Indigo. Following the instructions in "OSGi in Practice".

Same thing here. I don't know of a solution yet, but I will come back if I find one.

EDIT: Well, OK, it doesn't help you. But you wanted to know if someone else got it, and now you know. I do, and I was also looking for a solution.

EDIT#2: I made some progress. I looked up the source in github. Bnd expects to find a project called "cnf" in the Workspace. Gooling that shows other people having issues with that cnf project, when not all their project are in the workspace directory itself. I also understand that Bnd should actually create that cnf project itself, so this is where the real problem is. It just doesn't get created for some reason.

EDIT3: OK. Got it now. The following link explains what cnf is:

[Create a new Bnd OSGi project](http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/osgi_server/create_bnd_project/)

So I just created an empty cnf directory in the Workspace, and it then "Make Bundle" worked, so that is what you need, an empty directory called cnf.